# TableView slow when adding images to cellForRowAtIndex

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, asynchronous

I have this one line of code, which is retrieving an image from my `API`. However although this works, the app is running quite slow, when I run the code to retrieve the image.

I am using the `UITableView`. When I comment the code out it seems to run smoothly, is there a better way in using this code to make the app run faster? **My code:**

```
 if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string:events[indexPath.row].image! )!) {
     cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(data: data)
 }
```

Comment: His question is with swift, not obj-c

Comment: @Patrick yes you are right, haha and im a woman :)

Comment: Jajaja I´m sorry Ayesha. I hope my answer help you. Good luck!! :) :) :)

Comment: haha no its cool thanks! @Patrick :)